# d3 scoping causes SVG to revert to initial data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and still a beginner in javascript in general. I've got d3 correctly drawing a single SVG rectangle based on a single value in an array. When I increase the value of the number in the area via an input field and then call the reDraw function, the rectangle changes to the new size for just a second and then switches back to the initial size. I'm thinking I must have a scoping problem, but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

```
var dataset, h, reDraw, svg, w;

w = 300;

h = 400;

dataset = [1000];

// Create SVG element
svg = d3.select("#left").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

// set size and position of bar
svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset).enter().append("rect").attr("x", 120).attr("y", function(d) {
  return h - (d / 26) - 2;
}).attr("width", 60).attr("height", function(d) {
  return d / 26;
}).attr("fill", "rgb(3, 100, 0)");

// set size and position of text on bar
svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset).enter().append("text").text(function(d) {
  return "$" + d;
}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("x", 150).attr("y", function(d) {
  return h - (d / 26) + 14;
}).attr("font-family", "sans-serif").attr("font-size", "12px").attr("fill", "white");

// grab the value from the input, add to existing value of dataset
$("#submitbtn").click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem("donationTotal", Number(localStorage.getItem("donationTotal")) + Number($("#donation").val()));
  dataset.shift();
  dataset.push(localStorage.getItem("donationTotal"));
  return reDraw();
});

// redraw the rectangle to new size
reDraw = function() {
  return svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset).attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d / 26) - 2;
  }).attr("height", function(d) {
    return d / 26;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to tell d3 how to match new data to existing data in the `reDraw` function. That is, you're selecting all rectangles in `reDraw` and then binding data to it without telling it the relation between the old and the new. So after the call to `data()`, the current selection (the one you're operating on) should be empty (not sure why something happens for you at all) while the `enter()` selection contains the new data and the `exit()` selection the old one.</strike>

You have several options to make this work. You could either operate on the `enter()` and `exit()` selections in your current setup, i.e. remove the old and add the new, or restructure your data such that you're able to match old and new. You could for example use an object with appropriate attributes instead of a single number. The latter has the advantage that you could add a transition from the old to the new size.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) for some more information on data joins.

**Edit:**

Turns out that this was actually not the issue, see comments.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate a section of one of Mike Bostock's tutorials in which enter() and exit() aren't needed for the redraw: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html  Here is the relevant instruction: "No enter and exit selection is needed! Without a data join, the data are joined to nodes by index. As the length of the data array is fixed, the number of nodes never changes, and thus the enter and exit selections are always empty."  But I can't get it to work in a very basic setup: http://signaldesign.net/staffordschool/donation.html

Comment: Ah ok, having the complete example helped :) The page is refreshed when you click the submit button, causing the original value to appear. Simply `return false;` at the end of the handler function and the page won't be refreshed. It would also be better to get the current value from `localStorage` instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Bingo! And, duh. Sheesh, can't believe I forgot that. I forget why I decided to hard-code it. Something to do with testing it. But when I changed it the way you suggested it turned out I don't need the reDraw function at all. D3 updates my bar instantly. My client can go to this page to update the thermometer: http://signaldesign.net/staffordschool/donation3.html and his visitors can go to this page to see the thermometer and the accompanying photos and text: http://signaldesign.net/staffordschool/donation3.html Thanks much Lars!

Comment: Of course, now I have to figure out how to update it without localStorage. That only works for the browser and user that is doing the updating. Anyone else going to that page won't have that piece of data.

Comment: Yes, the only way to do that would be to store the value on the server in a database or something like that.